# How to refresh Service?

Tags: android, service, refresh, oncreate

I have some Service with onCreate method. In this onCreate method I have some processes and I need to still run this processes repeated all the time from start. I can't use infinite loop, because then my Service force close, I think it is not possible to use infinite loop in onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start a [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) in your `onCreate` method, and do all the processing inside that `Thread`. Make sure to stop that `Thread` when you no longer need it (maybe when the `Service` is stopped) .